# Whats the difference between Twitter consumer Key and Secret Key?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am new to Twitter Development. Right now, I have both consumer key and secret key provided to me. But I don't know where to use which one. A simple javascript code for loging in is not working. I actually want to tweet the score of the game. Anyone please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Twitter has a great getting started guide.  https://dev.twitter.com/start

From twitter's site:

> OAuth settings
>
> Your application's OAuth settings. Keep the "Consumer secret" a secret. This key should never be human-readable in your application.
>
> Your access token
>
> Use the access token string as your "oauth_token" and the access token secret as your "oauth_token_secret" to sign requests with your own Twitter account. Do not share your oauth_token_secret with anyone.