# What's the difference between twitter consumer key and access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise

I am following railscasts [235-devise-and-omniauth-revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised). The first step is setting up a [twitter app](http://dev.twitter.com) credential. I found that there is

Consumer key/Consumer secret

and also

Access token/Access token secret

My question is simple, Why there are two pairs of credential, What's the right scenario to use them.

I noticed here is [another same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839550/whats-the-difference-between-twitter-consumer-key-and-secret-key), which is not help much.

Okay, Then, As far as I know, consumer_key pair is for server. access_key pair is for client. check below comment. Add your answer if you have other understanding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The consumer key is for your application and client tokens are for end users in your application's context.

If you want to call in just the application context, then consumer key is adequate. You'd be rate limited per application and won't be able to access user data that is not public.

With the user token context, you'll be rate limited per token/user, this is desirable if you have  several users and need to make more calls than application context rate limiting allows. 
Your total call capacity (usually per 15 minutes) = number_of_user_tokens X per_user_token_per_api_rate_limit. 
Also, this way you can access private user data.

Which to use depends on your scenarios.

Comment: I must be dense, but still don't have a intuitive understanding

Comment: The Consumer key/secret is specific to the application, while the Access token/secret is specific to the user. I believe (and someone can correct me if I'm wrong) that the Consumer pair is embedded in your application, while the Access pair is generated per user.  So for example, if you install a twitter app on your phone, it'll have the Consumer pair embedded in it by the app developer, but the Access pair will be generated when you log into Twitter in the app. It's a little confusing when learning, since you're the only user of your test code, but you still have to generate an Access pair.

Comment: @seren which would make sense, except that a 'static' access token pair can be generated per app.   If someone could write an example use case, where both the 'consumer key' and the single, app-related 'access token' pairs are utilised within an application, that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know for sure but:

I use tweetsharp with .NET and there I see that the consumer-pair is used to create a twitterservice to be able to execute some actions.. The accessToken-pair is used to sign requests with your own Twitter account

```
Dim service As TwitterService = New TwitterService(obj.consumer_key, obj.consumer_secret)
service.AuthenticateWith(obj.access_token, obj.access_token_secret)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I sorts of understand the consumer-pair is used to create a twitter service. 

Then, As you say, the access_token is used to create a client?

Comment: Well.. For example you have to make an Application for Twitter (for your site or application itself) to be able to create request in name of that site.

Then you can personalize this requests with accesstokens for the twitter account itself indeed