# Create a twitter feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

The [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) has utterly abysmal documentation, however, I gather I need to create an initializer with the following settings:

```
:consumer_key       => ENV["CONSUMER_KEY"],
:consumer_secret    => ENV["CONSUMER_SECRET"],
:oauth_token        => ENV["OAUTH_TOKEN"],
:oauth_token_secret => ENV["OAUTH_SECRET"],
```

This has been a nightmare. I can't find these keys anywhere. I've signed into my account, created an app (have no idea if this is an app of my account or what?) and all I can find is an `api key` and an `api secret`. That's the nearest I can find.

I still don't know if I'm doing it right. Say I have an account `example3243`:

1. Visit https://dev.twitter.com/
2. Sign in as `example3243`
3. Click `create_app` and give it a name
4. **Find these damn keys**
5. Add `gem 'twitter'` to the gemfile and run `bundle install`
6. Run `rails c` and do the following:

   ```
   2.0.0p247 :010 > Twitter.user_timeline("example3243")
   # hopefully this returns all of `example3243`s tweets!
   ```

Okay, please help me get to step 6. Can't believe how absurdly difficult this is. Why all this key rubbish for read only?

Comment: There are per application (api_key aka consumer_key & api secret aka consumer_secret) and per user (on behalf of semantics) keys in which an application can call twitter. I recommend starting with per application to get a better understanding. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720752/whats-the-difference-between-twitter-consumer-key-and-access-token/20725013#20725013